# WebView съедает много памяти. Как выполнить очистку?

Tags: webview, android, утечка-памяти, memory

Думаю всем известна эта проблема. Она существует на всех версиях андроида и как от неё избавится я пока не нашёл. При открытии активити с вебвью приложение съедает дополнительно 8 мегабайт (может и больше). При закрытии окна (и соответственно вызове всевозможных clear, destroy, = null) помять не освобождается. Более того при заходе в активити снова, утекает ещё больше и больше памяти. Метод, заключающийся в вынесении создания WebView внутри кода, а не разметки не помогает. Подскажите, как исправить?

**Update**

```
public class CarWebViewActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle saved) {
    super.onCreate(saved);
    setContentView(R.layout.web_layout);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    final String href = extras.getString("href");

    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.header_title)).setText(extras.getString("title"));

    findViewById(R.id.web_layout_top_bar_button_reload).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (href != null)
                webView.loadUrl(href);
        }
    });

    LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.web_layout_root);
    webView = new WebView(getApplicationContext());
    root.addView(webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
    if (href != null)
        webView.loadUrl(href);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
    webView.getSettings().setBlockNetworkImage(false);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
}

WebView webView;

private final class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        Log.e("Ошибка страницы", "ошибка страницы");
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(CarWebViewActivity.this)
                .setMessage("Для отображения страницы необходимо интернет соединение")
                .setPositiveButton("Вернуться", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        finish();
                    }
                }).show();
        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
    }
}

public final class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
        try {
            findViewById(R.id.progressinheader).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.web_layout_top_bar_button_reload).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (progress == 100) {
                findViewById(R.id.progressinheader).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                findViewById(R.id.web_layout_top_bar_button_reload).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    webView.stopLoading();
    webView.clearCache(true);
    webView.clearView();
    webView.freeMemory();
    webView.destroy();
    webView = null;
    findViewById(R.id.progressinheader).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.about_item:
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AboutActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: ну неужели никто не знает?

Comment: Так разве эта память не удалиться потом? Это же андроид, он не будет освобождать память, пока есть свободная, и не надо ему больше.

Comment: пока что могу посоветовать это же задать на стеке =)

Comment: @Чад вы в курсе что у каждого приложения есть лимит на использование памяти, и при большом жоре система начинает закрывать неугодные. И наш апп с потреблением в 25-40 МБ будет первым на очереди. Про освобождение памяти я подробно описал в вопросе.
@Gorets там куча таких вопросов и единственный подходящий совет - не создавать вебвью, а открывать браузер

Comment: А как вы меряете утечку? У меня, например, при использовании веб вью в приложении, как ни удивительно, при запуске память наоборот даже больше становиться, и при открытии/закрытии утечек не обнаруживается(Android 4.0.3).

Comment: Может проблема всё же в чём-то другом? Я сомневаюсь что функциональность, существующая с API1, до сих пор не отработана и содержит такие грубые проблемы с памятью.

Comment: Так же наверное надо посмотреть как сделано в phoneGap - они то явно веб вью правильно юзают.

Comment: Да, кстате, при всяких clear, destroy, вы вызвали гарбжд коллектор?

Comment: @Чад в данном случае размер занимаемой памяти смотрится через ddms. phonegap очень лень ковырять по такому поводу. и последнее: это как это вы в jave явно вызываете gc?

Comment: в C# например существует `[GC.Collect();](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357.aspx)` наверняка и в java есть что-то подобное

Comment: плохо

public static void gc ()

Indicates to the VM that it would be a good time to run the garbage collector. Note that this is a hint only. There is no guarantee that the garbage collector will actually be run.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить mWebView.clearHistory(); mWebView.clearCache(true); mWebView.loadUrl("about:blank"); как здесь http://stackoverflow.com/a/17458577/2971719

Answer (score 2):

Вот нашёл по вызову Гарбадж коллекта в яве:

> Если присвоить ссылкам null и вызвать
> gc(), то он сработает лиш тогда, когда
> в потоке найдется время для выполнения
> gc(). Если поток занят, а памяти не
> хватает из-за ненужного объекта obj,
> можно попробовать

```
obj = null;
System.gc(); 
Thread.yield(); 
try {
  Thread.sleep(20); 
}
catch(Exception e){
}
```

Comment: Хоть мне это и не нравится, но попытка не пытка. Испытаю - отпишусь

Comment: отличная попытка, а смысл? вызнать System.gc();, а потом сделать паузу программы? зачем? думаешь в это время будет работать сборщик мусора?

Comment: ручной вызов gc - плохая практика.
Если программа не в бекграунде, то прибивать система ее будет в самую последнюю очередь. А вот если она в бекграунде и не сервис - так это на раз - такая идеология андроида.

Comment: @Gorets - пауза для того чтобы коллектор попробывал отработать - система его вызывает после просьбы "System.gc()" только если есть время для этого. Если поток в простое(sleep), то можно и вызвать.

Comment: А не обязан он вызываться. Если код будет полагаться на вызов GC - это плохой код.

Comment: Никто и не говорит что обязан. Но я и не понимаю почему при закрытии окна с WebView сразу должна память освободиться тоже.

Comment: Никто не говорил, что это правильно. Вызов System.gc() вообще не имеет смысла после webview = null; Но добавление последующего кода - стоит попробовать. А память действительно не должна освобождаться сразу, но она не освобождается вообще никогда

Comment: Мне кажется что беда всё же не в веб вью, а в каких-то других действиях сподручных. Что грузите туда, какие свойства выставляете, что ешё делает активити помимо инициализации веб вью и отображения чего-то в нём, и т.д.

Comment: хорошо, я понял. Привожу полный код активити. см апдэйт шапки

Comment: Наверное это всё же не влияет, но super.onDestroy(); надо вызывать после своих действий.

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    webView.stopLoading();
    webView.clearCache(true);
    webView.clearView();
    webView.freeMemory();
    webView.destroy();
    webView = null;
    findViewById(R.id.progressinheader).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    super.onDestroy();
}

Answer (score 0):

```
void clearCache(Context context)
{
    clearCacheFolder(context.getCacheFolder());
}

void clearCacheFolder(final File dir) 
{      
    if (dir!= null && dir.isDirectory()) 
    {         
        try 
        {             
            for (File child:dir.listFiles()) 
            {                  
               //рекурсивно чистим сначала каталоги                 
                if (child.isDirectory()) 
                    clearCacheFolder(child);
                else //потом собственно файлы
                    child.delete(); 
            }         
        }         
        catch(Exception e) 
        {             
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to clean the cache error message="+e.getMessage());         
        }     
    }     
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Стандартной причиной утечки памяти является попытка сохранения ссылок на `Activity/Context` в своих классах. Почитайте [хорошую статью](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) на эту тему

Comment: обратите внимание что вопрос задан не новичком в андроиде. Не ждал такого банального ответа

Comment: @alvin: Ну конечно профи издалека видно по вызову gc() в коде. Упражняйтесь дальше :)